# How to copy system/apps settings from one server to another?

Tags: configuration, windows-server-2012, migration, windows-server-2012-r2, server-setup

I have an instance of Windows Server 2012 running my website. This instance is 100% configured, with every single detail and fix I ever needed to perform. The problem is that now due to financial issues, we need to migrate to an instance with a lower configuration.
I don't want to configure every little thing again. I didn't document my actions so I will run into some already fixed problems for sure.

I need to copy IIS, Firewall, WebDeploy, Windows features, and so on.

Is there any way in which I could copy my current instance's settings? Any Windows option or 3rd party software?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like you just need to [make a backup](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj614621.aspx) and restore it to your new server.

Comment: Will it work in a server with a significantly smaller HD? I know I can't make images because of the HD size, will this backup feature work on this smaller HD? Provided of course I have enough space. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. You should read the documentation, it's very thorough.

Comment: Ok, then. I appreciate your help. Will mark as answer as soon as I'm able to test it. Thanks.

Comment: This is assuming your smaller server still has enough resources/space. Backup and restore will work fine - you can also backup the IIS metabase separately, but that should be unnecessary if you are doing bare metal backup/restore of the system. And who says you can't use imaging?

Comment: @Rex Rackspace's support. They said there is some variable that creates the new image based on the previous machine's disk size.